# Is concurrent quota for Big Query user dependent or dataset dependent?

Tags: google-bigquery

For Big Query (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas), is the quota for concurrent queries for each user or for each dataset?

Thank you for any response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery limits the maximum rate of incoming requests and enforces appropriate quotas on a **per-project** basis.

Comment: If i have a data studio report which fetches from google big query, lets say 10 bar charts, each one fetching from a different table in google bigquery, i guess that count as 10 concurrent request when i load the report?

Comment: if it is designed as a one query  - it will count as a one request. you can check your query history and see how exactly that data is being queried

Comment: just one more question, is concurrency measured in the same seconds, same minutes? or something else? So if i load the report, and somebody load the report a couple seconds after me, that is only 10 concurrent request at any given time?

Comment: i think it would be safe to count on 'by second' :o)